# Typescript Using external modules: export and import

Tags: typescript

As I read [here](https://codepen.io/martinmcwhorter/post/angularjs-1-x-with-typescript-or-es6-best-practices), using Namespaces in Typescript is not the best choice. Instead, I'm trying to use external modules, but I have some problems.

**File1.ts**

```
export class MySrv {
    // ...     
}
export let Services = angular.module("myApp.core").service("mySrv", MySrv);
```

**File2.ts**

```
"use strict";
import * as Services from "../core/mySrv";

class MainAreaCtrl {
    // ...   
}

export default angular.module("myApp.main-area").controller("MainAreaCtrl", MainAreaCtrl);
```

The problem I have is: **Uncaught: ReferenceError: Exports is not defined**

The question is: How is the correct way to import and export modules in TypeScript using ES2015 syntax?

Regards!

Comment: First of all: "use strict" isn't necessary. Second: How do you compile your TS-sources and how do you execute them?

Comment: If you run this in the browser you need to bundle your JavaScript with something as `webpack`/`browserify`.